# What is the I Rig

Tags: guitar, recording

I am interested in recording straight from guitar to my Ipad. I've seen the IRig for this but I am not sure what it is.

Is the IRig simply an audio jack to 3.5mm converter? Will it amplify the guitar output at all or will I need separate software?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The I rig is a device for converting guitar output signals to signals a phone can read in an app, which can then convert it to signals a mini amp can read. In the app, one can alter volume, octave, things a conventional amp could do. However you cannot notate music with it.